# Question about ASP.NET global variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, global

Might seem like a dumb question, but...

Say I have an ASP solution with a Globals.vb file. Inside that file, I have this:

```
Public Shared MyVariable As String
```

Now say I publish this solution and make it available to Bob and Cindy.

If Cindy sets (through the interface) MyVariable to 5, would Bob be able to read it?

I hope not, I'm hoping this variable would be user-specific.

Thanks in advance for letting me know.

Best Regards,

Jason

Comment: I asked the same question awhile back, see the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026785/how-do-static-properties-work-in-an-asp-net-enviroment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bob would be able to read that it was 5 because it's `Shared`

more information here: [What is the use of a shared variable in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613998/what-is-the-use-of-shared-variable-in-vb-net)