# Are private static variable inside non-static class available to the entire application?

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
...
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private static string _code = null;
...
```

Will the `_code` variable be shared with everyone on my application who loads `MyPage`?

## This question is not a Duplicate

The possible duplicate does not address static variables inside a non-static class.  I now know it does not matter, however, the "duplicate" does not say this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do static properties work in an asp.net enviroment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026785/how-do-static-properties-work-in-an-asp-net-enviroment)

Comment: @finnw I said `_code` variable in my question but was originally going to have it as a property when I was writing the title... SO SORRY! (downvote? really?)

Comment: I did not downvote you (but I did vote to close as duplicate.)

Comment: @asawyer The "duplicate" does not address static variables inside a non-static class. I now know it does not matter, however, you're "duplicate" does not say this.

Comment: @capdragon I'm sorry if you don't agree, and I did not downvote. The question, in my opinion is an duplicate because it addresses static value behavior in asp.net applications. I had asked the same thing before and thought the information I received would be useful to you. The close vote is simply the mechanism provided. There is no reason to get bent out of shape.

Comment: I still think it's a duplicate.  The difference is not significant enough to justify a separate question.

Comment: i think this is a very useful question and is helping me figure out if i can do that is said in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be shared across the application domain. Since a single app domain is created for each IIS Application within an IIS worker thread, the value of the static variable can be considered shared globally.

Answer (score 3):

yes, static members of non static classes are anyway static.