# Is it safe to use a Shared property for authentication verification?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, shared, public

Should I be using `Shared`, or just a `Public` function and initiate a class when needed? I have read a number of articles, but still cant get my head around the best option here.

Here is the code I want to get. The `userid` in question is a string that's set when the user logs in. As I may need the userid in a number of pages, I want to add it in a class.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property userid As String
    Get
        Dim ck As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
        Dim tkt As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(ck.Value)
        Return tkt.Name
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: The key to this is the context the call operates in. In this case the property reads from a session value so it would work fine. That's not always the case. Take a look at this question I asked a few years ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026785/how-do-static-properties-work-in-an-asp-net-enviroment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would almost never say that you should leverage a `Shared` member when dealing with authentication - but since you're using `Cookies` I can't see any reason this code wouldn't work as is and make it easier to access.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine and acceptable. You can see accessing `HttpContext.Current` inside static method in a lot of open source projects.

**FYI:** `HttpContext.Current` must be on current calling thread, so make sure to check `HttpContext.Current` is not null.